# how can i filter only .sql files using directory.getfiles

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directory, getfiles

I am trying to filter the only.sql files from given Directory path

But it will compress the all files in the given directorypath

```
      string directorypath = @"C:\access";

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directorypath);

        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles().Where(.sql))
        {

            CompressionMethod(fi);


        }
```

but , i want send only .sql files to this method CompressionMethod(fi) .... how can i do 
that

would any one pls help on this...

many thanks....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `di.GetFiles("*.sql")`

Answer (score 2):

there exists an overload of GetFiles with a searchpattern: GetFiles(string searchpattern)

so use:

```
di.GetFiles("*.sql")
```